# How can I determine which UIControlEvents type caused a UIEvent?

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, controls

What I want to do is set up a bunch of `UIControl` objects to send all events through the same handler. That handler than needs to determine what the appropriate action is based on the `UIControlEvents` type that triggered.

```
- (void)handleEventFromControl:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIControl *control = sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [controlIndexPaths objectForKey:control];
    UIControlEvents controlEventType = event.type; //PROBLEM HERE

    BOOL fire = NO;
    NSNumber *eventCheck = [registeredEventsByToolkitIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.toolkit];
    fire = ([eventCheck integerValue] & controlEventType);

    if(!fire) {
        eventCheck = [registeredEventsByControlIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.control];
        fire = ([eventCheck integerValue] & controlEventType);
    }

    if(!fire) {
        eventCheck = [registeredEventsByIndexPath objectForKey:indexPath];
        fire = ([eventCheck integerValue] & controlEventType);
    }

    if(fire) {
        [self.delegate toolkit:self indexPath:indexPath firedEvent:event];
    }
}
```

As best as I can tell, `event.type` doesn't work this way. I want to avoid having a subclass of `UIControl` because that is severe overkill for what I want to do. The rest of the moving parts here aren't really that important; what I want is a way to check against `UIControlEvents` after the `target:action:` pair is used in the following setup:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

If there is a different way to setup of a `target:action:` that sends back the `UIControlEvents`, I'd take that. But I am not seeing it in the documentation. Or, at the very least, get access *outside* of the `UIControl` object such that I can get the type I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437875/target-action-uicontrolevents

Comment: @albertamg: Yes, that question exactly covers the same ground as this one. Any voters passing through, go ahead and close this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're correct; `UIEvent.type` does not work that way.  Internally, `UIControl` subclasses are basically using the [`sendActionsForControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW1) method, which means they can choose to put anything they want as the parameter.

As for how to know, the simple answer is to have a separate method for each control event.