# iOS fetch UIButton current UIControlEventType at @selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

```
let aButton = UIButton()
a.addTarget(self, action: "handler:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func handler(btn: UIButton) {
    //Is there anyway can I know the controlEvent is "TouchUpInside" in this method?
}
```

as the example above, I wanna know the ControlEventType at @selector, could not found the correct API or it's impossible?

Comment: method is called if and only if control event is touchUpInside. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076741/how-to-distinguish-between-fired-events-for-a-uibutton-callback-action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either provide different methods for the different control events:

```
a.addTarget(self, action: "touchDownHandler:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
a.addTarget(self, action: "touchUpHandler:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func touchDownHandler(btn: UIButton) {
}

func touchUpHandler(btn: UIButton) {
}
```

As noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406318/2613662) you can also get the event in your handler and inspect that for the type of touch, here it is in Swift:

```
a.addTarget(self, action: "handleTouch:event:", forControlEvents: .AllTouchEvents)

// ...

func handleTouch(button: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = event.touchesForView(button)?.first as? UITouch {
        switch touch.phase {
        case .Began:
            println("touch began")

        case .Ended:
            println("touch ended")

        case .Moved:
            println("touch moved")

        case .Cancelled:
            println("touch cancelled")

        case .Stationary:
            println("touch stationary")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your action to take the event parameter, like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(callback:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown | UIControlEventTouchCancel];

-(void)callback:(UIButton *)button (UIEvent*)event {
    ...
}
```

Adding a second parameter to your callback will make Cocoa pass the event to you, so that you could check what has triggered the callback.

thanks to [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to create multiple functions (which could then call a common handler function, of course):

```
a.addTarget(self, action: "handleTouchUpInside:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
a.addTarget(self, action: "handleTouchUpOutside:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpOutside)
```

You are allowed to add an action which accepts an extra `UIEvent` parameter, but unfortunately it won't contain any information about the control event type.